# Sendgrid API returns Forbidden C#

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I am doing everything as it is shown in sendgrid's documentation

```
    var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
    var from = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
    var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
    var to = new EmailAddress("whereiwanttosendemail@mail.com", "Example User");
    var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
    var htmlContent = "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with C#</strong>";
    var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
    var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
```

[image]

Comment: Take C# out of the equation - are you able to use Postman to send an email with SendGrid? _My bet is your apikey is wrong._

Comment: if I put wrong api key it says 'Unauthorized'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'From' mail should be registered in SendGrid as a verified sender.
Settings -> Sender Authentication.